# Is there a browser API that provides access to the built in list of languages?

Tags: browser, internationalization, chromium

In my application, I have a localized list of languages that is sent down from the server when the application loads.

The browser already contains a localized list of languages (you can see it by going to `settings > languages > add a language` in a chromium browser (see photo below).

**Is there an API that will retrieve the same localized list of languages? I am trying to avoid managing additional localized text, if possible.**

[image: settings > languages > add a language]